# Java new BigDecimal generates another number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm using BigDecimal data type, when I set

```
new BigDecimal(21.30);
```

then, I returned it as xml source, it shows as

```
21.30000000000710522735760100185871124467578125
```

Another number

```
new BigDecimal(23.11)
```

returned

```
23.1099999994315658113818187512921995859375
```

I want to show results with the same decimals as I set on create.

Comment: Can you please provide the code with which you are creating the XML in the form of a [mcve]?

Comment: Have you tried `new BigDecimal("21.30");` and `new BigDecimal("23.11");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>   might assume that writing `new BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates
>   a `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.
>
> This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a `double` (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length).  Thus, the value that is being passed *in* to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, 
>   appearances notwithstanding.

If you check the BigDecimal java doc you will find out that you will have to use the constructor which takes a `String` parameter to end up with the behavior you need.

Comment: Simply adding `new BigDecimal("23.11")` would have been nice. Use backticks ` to quote code inside other text. Use indentation with 4 spaces for code blocks.

Comment: The above quoted text is taken from [the constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E%28double%29).